# How to get mouse click and release position using override virtual paint()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am having QGraphicsView which contains different QGraphicsItem's like rectangle,polyline,text etc. I have installed event filter through which I am managing mouse click and release event and creating rubber band rectangle. Whichever area comes under rubber band rectangle, it gets zoom in.
I am storing rubber band rectangle points in local variables like `rubberBandOrigin` ( mouse click position ) and `rubberBandEnd` ( mouse release position)
When I click on any item's, its `paint()` method gets called.  I want to use `rubberBandOrigin` and `rubberBandEnd` variables in `paint()` method.

The way I was told that, you will get these variables ( means mouse click position and release position ) through `paint()` itself.
`paint()` has 3rd parameter `QWidget *widget`. Through this, you will get mouse click and release position (i.e. rubber band rectangle position)
Here is my code:

```
bool guiSchematicViewUtil::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    bool filterEvent = false;
      switch(event->type())
      {
          case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
          {
            QMouseEvent * mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
             rubberBandOrigin = mouseEvent->pos();
            rubberBandActive = true;
            break;
          }
          case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
          {
            if (rubberBandActive)
            {
               QMouseEvent * mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
               rubberBandEnd = mouseEvent->pos();   
     
              QGraphicsView * view = static_cast<QGraphicsView *>(watched->parent());
              QRectF zoomRectInScene = QRectF(view->mapToScene(rubberBandOrigin),
                                              view->mapToScene(rubberBandEnd));

              view->fitInView(zoomRectInScene, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
              rubberBandActive = false;
            }
            break;
          }
      default:
          break;
      }

      return filterEvent;
}
```

paint method:

```
void guiSchematicRect::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
  // Here I want rubberBandOrigin and rubberBandEnd co-ordinates using QWidget* widget parameter
}
```

I tried with api like parent(), parentWidget() of QWidget but did not get it.
Can any one help me ?

Comment: To ask a question, you need to explain all the relation between the class you posted. The caller, callee and the relation of all of them.

Comment: @LouisGo It is the same this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391014/how-to-get-value-of-variables-from-different-files-using-extern-in-qt/71392331?noredirect=1#comment126234580_71392331 But told that no need to pass the variable through constructor or any way,(that's difficult way) you will get clicked position on child widget through , `paint()` 3rd argument i.e. `QWidget* widget`  Now not understanding, how will I get mouse click and release position in `paint()` itself ?